# How would I make my bot say something when a channel is created under a category?

Tags: discord.py

I'm trying to make my Discord bot say something and have message awaits when a channel is created, etc however I'm not sure how to do that, here is the code I'm dealing with right now:

```
import discord, asyncio

discord_token = open('token.txt').read()
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.lower().startswith('test'):
        await message.channel.send('testing, sending to channel works!')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Successfully connected to', client.user)

client.run(discord_token)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using **[`on_guild_channel_create`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_guild_channel_create)**

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_create(channel):
    if channel.category: #if the channel created is in a category
        #send something
        await channel.send("Something")
```